# Lavaan: SEM through time

Tags: r, mixed-model, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I have fitted a (quite complex) SEM model with `lavaan` at two time points (T1 and T2) and would like to know if my model T2 holds through time or not, and if not, what are the parameters that significantly changed through time.

I am not familiar with the SEM approach, so what I would normally do is to have my `time` variable as a moderator of every path of my model. However, I feel that this is not the best approach.

Here some data that can be used as an exemple:

```r
library(lavaan)

set.seed(1234)
n <- 100

model <- '# latent variable
            X =~ x1 + x2 + x3
          # direct effect
            Y ~ c*X
          # mediator
            M ~ a*X
            Y ~ b*M
          # indirect effect (a*b)
            ab := a*b
          # total effect
            total := c + (a*b)'

# T1
X <- rnorm(n)
x1 <- X + rnorm(n)
x2 <- X + rnorm(n)
x3 <- X + rnorm(n)
M <- 0.5*X + rnorm(n)
Y <- 0.7*M + rnorm(n)
DF1 <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, Y, M, Time = "T1")
fit1 <- sem(model, data = DF1)
summary(fit1)

# T2
X <- rnorm(n)
x1 <- X + rnorm(n)
x2 <- X + rnorm(n)
x3 <- X + rnorm(n)
M <- 0.3*X + rnorm(n)
Y <- 0.4*M + rnorm(n)
DF2 <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, Y, M, Time = "T2")
fit2 <- sem(model, data = DF2)
summary(fit2)

# T1 vs T2
DF <- rbind(DF1, DF2)
```

I heard that maybe I could use "growth curves" or "Multilevel SEM" but I am not familiar with those. Any input would be appreciated.

---

**Edit**
We can assume that T1 and T2 are independent observations.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could define a single lavaan model syntax for both timepoints, with the proper constraints. Then, you would just use a likelihood ratio test to see if the constraints across waves change the fit significantly compared with a freely estimated model.

Comment: @Kuku Sounds like a neat idea. Would you mind to share how would you code this constrains? Or do you have any reference/tutorial for a similar case?

Comment: You can rule out growth curve models because you only have 2 time points here as opposed to the recommended minimum of 3 (Curran, Obeidat, & Losardo, 2010).

Following up on @Kuku's advice, this page should give you all the details necessary to do a multi-group equality constraint test. Since you stated that your T1 and T2 samples are independent, we can just think of them as two distinct groups like men and women or people from different countries.

https://psu-psychology.github.io/psy-597-SEM/10_invariance_groups/invariance_groups_constraints.html#how-to-test-constraints-in-lavaan

Answer (score 3):

Below I have modified your code with the proposed solution.

In this specific case, we can see that there is not a significant difference in fit between the freely estimated model and the constrained across waves model. In other words, estimating the same parameters for both waves gives a more parsimonious model with not too much of a price to pay. This is expected (and you can play with different parameters), as the data generating process for both time points is structurally the same. In case you find a significant difference and want to do exploratory analysis on which specific constraint is affecting your fit, you can ask for modification indices using lavaan.

It is worth noting that there is not too much context for your problem. Depending on the specifics of your problem, you may also care about absolute measures of fit (such as SRMR), the choice of estimator and the parametrization of your model (especially if you have ordinal outcomes).

Regarding literature or references, as @Rak well mentions, invariance is the key word. If you check for measurement invariance or group invariance you are sure to find practical and theoretical material about it. Below I give a list of references (from more practical to more theoretical) that may be helpful, although focalized on the psychometric applications of measurement invariance:

- [Putnick, D. L., & Bornstein, M. H. (2016). Measurement invariance
  conventions and reporting: The state of the art and future directions
  for psychological research. Developmental review, 41, 71-90.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0273229716300351)
- [Widaman, K. F., Ferrer, E., & Conger, R. D. (2010). Factorial
  invariance within longitudinal structural equation models: Measuring
  the same construct across time. Child development perspectives, 4(1),
  10-18.](http://Widaman,%20K.%20F.,%20Ferrer,%20E.,%20&%20Conger,%20R.%20D.%20(2010).%20Factorial%20%20%20%20invariance%20within%20longitudinal%20structural%20equation%20models:%20Measuring%20%20%20%20the%20same%20construct%20across%20time.%20Child%20development%20perspectives,%204(1),%20%20%20%2010-18.)
- [Svetina, D., Rutkowski, L., & Rutkowski, D. (2020). Multiple-group
  invariance with categorical outcomes using updated guidelines: an
  illustration using M plus and the lavaan/semtools packages.
  Structural Equation Modeling: A Multidisciplinary Journal, 27(1),
  111-130.](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10705511.2019.1602776)
- [Muthén, B., & Asparouhov, T. (2002). Latent variable analysis with
  categorical outcomes: Multiple-group and growth modeling in Mplus.
  Mplus web notes, 4(5), 1-22.](https://www.statmodel.com/download/webnotes/CatMGLong.pdf)
- [Wu, H., & Estabrook, R. (2016). Identification of confirmatory factor
  analysis models of different levels of invariance for ordered
  categorical outcomes. Psychometrika, 81(4), 1014-1045.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11336-016-9506-0)

```
library(lavaan)

set.seed(1234)
n <- 100

# 1. Data Input -----------------------------------------------------------

### T1
X_t1 <- rnorm(n)
x1_t1 <- X_t1 + rnorm(n)
x2_t1 <- X_t1 + rnorm(n)
x3_t1 <- X_t1 + rnorm(n)
M_t1 <- 0.5*X_t1 + rnorm(n)
Y_t1 <- 0.7*M_t1 + rnorm(n)
DF1 <- data.frame(x1_t1, x2_t1, x3_t1, Y_t1, M_t1)

### T2
X_t2 <- rnorm(n)
x1_t2 <- X_t2 + rnorm(n)
x2_t2 <- X_t2 + rnorm(n)
x3_t2 <- X_t2 + rnorm(n)
M_t2 <- 0.5*X_t2 + rnorm(n)
Y_t2 <- 0.7*M_t2 + rnorm(n)
DF2 <- data.frame(x1_t2, x2_t2, x3_t2, Y_t2, M_t2)

# Dataframe
DF <- cbind(DF1, DF2)


# 2. Model Syntax ---------------------------------------------------------

model_free <- '
          #Time 1

          # latent variable
            X_t1 =~ x1_t1 + x2_t1 + x3_t1
          # direct effect
            Y_t1 ~ c*X_t1
          # mediator
            M_t1 ~ a*X_t1
            Y_t1 ~ b*M_t1
          # indirect effect (a*b)
            ab := a*b
          # total effect
            total_t1 := c + (a*b)

           # Time 2
           
          # latent variable
            X_t2 =~ x1_t2 + x2_t2 + x3_t2
          # direct effect
            Y_t2 ~ d*X_t2
          # mediator
            M_t2 ~ e*X_t2
            Y_t2 ~ f*M_t2
          # indirect effect (e*f)
            ef := e*f
          # total effect
            total_t2 := d + (e*f)'

model_constrained <- '
          #Time 1

          # latent variable
            X_t1 =~ x1_t1 + x2_t1 + x3_t1
          # direct effect
            Y_t1 ~ c*X_t1
          # mediator
            M_t1 ~ a*X_t1
            Y_t1 ~ b*M_t1
          # indirect effect (a*b)
            ab := a*b
          # total effect
            total_t1 := c + (a*b)

          # Time 2
           
          # latent variable
            X_t2 =~ x1_t2 + x2_t2 + x3_t2
          # direct effect
            Y_t2 ~ c*X_t2
          # mediator
            M_t2 ~ a*X_t2
            Y_t2 ~ b*M_t2
          # indirect effect (a*b)
            ab := a*b
          # total effect
            total_t2 := c + (a*b)'


# 3. Model Fit ------------------------------------------------------------

fit_free <- lavaan::sem(model_free, data = DF)
fit_constrained <- lavaan::sem(model_constrained, data = DF)

# 4. Likelihood Ratio Test ------------------------------------------------

lavaan::lavTestLRT(fit_free, fit_constrained)

# Chi-Squared Difference Test
# 
#                 Df    AIC    BIC  Chisq Chisq diff Df diff Pr(>Chisq)
# fit_free        31 3125.2 3187.7 33.608                              
# fit_constrained 34 3124.2 3178.9 38.653     5.0452       3     0.1685
```